# Does Geth Clique will get affected when difficulty increases to its maximum?

Tags: mining, poa, difficulty, geth-clique

I have started own private network with clique consensus algorithm in GETH. Regardless of miners now sealer will do the job and I have `period:5`. Difficulty is set `0` initially but over time it is going to be increased.

So when it reaches to around 100's of billion , does that going to affect the performance? At that level of difficulty will the miners keep appearing every 5 sec?

Answer (score 3):

In Clique Proof-of-Authority consensus algorithm the difficulty does not increase with the chain lenght (unlike the Proof-of-Work). In fact the term of "difficulty" is not relevant in PoA as there is no puzzle solving.
This term is still used as a block property to meet the yellow paper specification, but we prefer to talk about `block score` rather than "difficulty" (see why below).

Let's see the [Clique EIP](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-225) where the difficulty is defined :

```
difficulty: Contains the standalone score of the block to derive the quality 
of a chain.
Must be DIFF_NOTURN if BLOCK_NUMBER % SIGNER_COUNT != SIGNER_INDEX
Must be DIFF_INTURN if BLOCK_NUMBER % SIGNER_COUNT == SIGNER_INDEX
```

With :

```
DIFF_NOTURN: Block score (difficulty) for blocks containing out-of-turn signatures.
Suggested 1 since it just needs to be an arbitrary baseline constant.
DIFF_INTURN: Block score (difficulty) for blocks containing in-turn 
signatures.
Suggested 2 to show a slight preference over out-of-turn signatures.
```

**Difficulty is equal to either 1 or 2 and refers to the *quality* of the chain**. The default difficulty should be set to 0x1 in the genesis file.

In Clique PoA, the proposed blocks have a weight and the sealers have a turn. When it is the turn of a sealer, this one will have the privilege of proposing a block with a difficulty (weight) of 2. Such a block is privileged by the network compared to those of weight 1 proposed by "out-of-turn" sealers. This process improves the security of the consensus algorithm and therefore the security of the chain.

To conclude, your PoA blockchain should continue to forge blocks every 5 seconds as long as all your sealers are active. If an "in-turn" validator is offline, the block will be broadcasted with a short delay of `rand(SIGNER_COUNT * 500ms)` (SIGNER_COUNT = number of sealers).

Comment: That is interesting. This seems like I won't be facing the slow mining issue as in PoW algorithm over time when difficulty increased to some billions or trillions. Whatever the difficulty number the signer keeps mining it in every 5 seconds of interval forever if everything runs under control. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In PoA, the difficulty has not this exponential impact on block period we could see in PoW. Furthermore it cannot growth, difficulty is either 1 or 2, as explained in the answer. So yes, your chain will continue mining blocks with an interval of 5 seconds for ever.